# How can I get Total Deposit of Customers

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project with 2 Models; Customer and Deposit and I want to display a list of Customers with their names, deposited dated, account number, and Total Deposited within the year so how do I do it the right way.
See what I have tried but Couldn't get the Customers' name in my Django Templates.

Models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    othernames = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True) 

    #Get the url path of the view
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('customer_create', args=[self.id])

    #Making Sure Django Display the name of our Models as it is without Pluralizing
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Customer'

#
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.surname} {self.othernames} - {self.account_number}' 

class Deposit(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    acct = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    deposit_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True) 
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('create_account', args=[self.id])

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.customer} Deposited {self.deposit_amount} by {self.staff.username}'
```

here is my view code:

```
def customer_list(request):
    #Get Current Date
    current_date = datetime.now().date()
    #Get Current Month Name from Calendar
    current_month_name = calendar.month_name[date.today().month]
    group_deposits = Deposit.objects.filter(date__year=current_date.year).order_by('acct')
    grouped_customer_deposit = group_deposits.values('acct').annotate(total `=Sum('deposit_amount')).order_by()`
context = { 'customers':grouped_customer_deposit,}
```

Here is how I tried to display the result in Django Template:

```
{% for deposit in customers %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td> 
                <td>{{ deposit.acct }}</td>
                <td>{{ deposit.customer.surname }}</td>
                <td>{{ deposit.total }}</td>
                <td>{{ customer.deposit.date }}</td>
                
                <th scope="row"><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=" ">Deposit</a></th>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
```

Someone should graciously help with the most efficient way of getting the Total Deposit for each customer with their names, account number, and date deposited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the `values` method:

```
grouped_customer_deposit = group_deposits.values('acct').annotate(total `=Sum('deposit_amount')).order_by()`
```

Django will return a queryset that returns dictionaries rather than model instances. See [Django Queryset API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) for more details.

This means that you cannot reference your model relationships as you are trying to do here:

```
<td>{{ deposit.customer.surname }}</td>
```

as that information will not be in the dictionary passed to the template (you can do a `print` of `grouped_customer_deposit` in your view, or display it in your template -- `{{ customers }}` -- to see what I mean).

Ergo, if you remove your call to values() then your template will receive model instances which should solve your problem, and make your template work as-is.

```
grouped_customer_deposit = group_deposits.annotate(total `=Sum('deposit_amount')).order_by()`
```

(Although your syntax for your `annotate` is not correct, so I'm assuming that was a mistake when you pasted your code here.)